# How to set yarn job queue for Titan MR job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, titan

Titan version is 1.0.0 ​whatever I tried, all yarn applications ended up in the default queue. these are the things I tried:

1) setting property in the titan-hbase-solr.properties (none of the following worked)

```
mapred.job.queue.name=myqueue 
mapreduce.job.queue.name=myqueue 
mapred.mapreduce.job.queue.name=myqueue
```

2) setting property in the gremlin shell

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("/usr/iop/4.2.5.0-0000/titan/conf/titan-hbase-solr.properties") 
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement() 
gremlin> desc = mgmt.getPropertyKey("desc") 
gremlin> mr = new MapReduceIndexManagement(graph) 

gremlin> mgmt.set('gremlin.hadoop.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.gremlin]: 

hadoop gremlin> mgmt.set('hadoop.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root]: hadoop Display stack trace? [yN] n 

gremlin> mgmt.set('titan.hadoop.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root]: titan Display stack trace? [yN] n 

gremlin> mgmt.set('mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root]: mapred Display stack trace? [yN] n gremlin> 

gremlin> mgmt.set('mapreduce.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root]: mapreduce Display stack trace? [yN] n 

gremlin> mgmt.set('gremlin.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.gremlin]: mapred Display stack trace? [yN] n 

gremlin> mgmt.set('gremlin.hadoop.mapred.job.queue.name', 'myqueue') 
Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.gremlin]: hadoop Display stack trace? [yN] n
```

Comment: Can you try [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph) and see if that works for you? JanusGraph is a recent fork of Titan; Titan hasn't been updated since 2015. Here's a [blog post](http://yaaics.blogspot.nl/2017/07/configuring-janusgraph-for-spark-yarn.html) for how you can configure JanusGraph + YARN.

Comment: @MishaBrukman, thanks for your response. I am absolutely aware about JanusGraph being the successor for Titan. The thing is, I am asking this particular question because there is a situation where Titan is part of a legacy system and it cannot be replaced with JanusGraph.

Comment: Understood; see my answer with more details as to what I think may be causing this issue and how you may be able to move forward. Please let me know if that works for you; if you find an alternative solution, please post another answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

YARN is a feature of Hadoop 2.0; however, Titan 1.0 does not fully support Hadoop 2.0 (see quote below), so this may be causing the issue you're seeing.

Some folks have forked Titan 1.0 to add support for TinkerPop 3.1 which adds support for Hadoop 2.x, e.g., see [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/graben1437/titan1withtp3.1). There's also a [Titan bug](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1329) and [discussion on the `thinkaurelius@` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/06biFFbS2xc/blNk51pABQAJ) with a similar topic which you may find useful, and one of the posts references that fork.

As an alternative to using a Titan 1.0 fork which upgraded Titan to 3.1.x, you may also consider the unreleased [Titan 1.1 branch](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/tree/titan11) which depends on TinkerPop 3.1.1-incubating, and thus may be suitable for use with Hadoop 2.x and YARN. [Titan 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/BQRAe4pxHaQ/QkvVBSlXFgAJ) may be useful for you; see [artifacts on Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/thinkaurelius/titan/titan-core/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/).

Here's the info from the [Titan wiki](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads) which explains which TinkerPop and Hadoop versions are supported by Titan 1.0:

> Titan 1.0.0 itself is compatible with both Hadoop 1 and 2, but TinkerPop’s hadoop-gremlin requires Hadoop 1. hadoop-gremlin contains graph computer implementations for running traversals on Spark and Giraph, among other bits.
>
> This will change in later TinkerPop releases. Titan 1.0.0 depends on TinkerPop 3.0.1-incubating. However, support for Hadoop 2 has been announced for the TinkerPop 3.1.0 release: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/VB5D61L-xm8/_0MKqcTdAQAJ
>
> Once TinkerPop 3.1.0 is released, subsequent Titan can restore full Hadoop 2 support. Hadoop 1 support will be retained if doing so is painless; if it raises conflicts, then it may be dropped.
>
> However, for Titan 1.0.0 with TinkerPop 3.0.1-incubating, the situation is reversed: only Hadoop 1 can be fully supported in the zipfile distribution on account of hadoop-gremlin, and Hadoop 2 support is offered only insofar as conflicts around hadoop-gremlin can be avoided. The Hadoop 1 zipfile offers all of the functionality of its Hadoop 2 counterpart, except that it lacks titan-solr and it can’t talk to Hadoop 2 clusters (generally including HBase clusters running on top of Hadoop 2). The Hadoop 2 zipfile is missing the following features compared with its Hadoop 1 counterpart:
>
> - The Hadoop 2 zipfile lacks titan-hadoop and hadoop-gremlin
> - The Hadoop 2 zipfile lacks MapReduceIndexJobs
> - The Hadoop 2 zipfile is not as well-tested as the Hadoop 1 zipfile; it’s possible that other bits are broken but yet undiscovered